# select multiple weeks jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have this jsfiddle code which is working for a week selection

```
https://jsfiddle.net/gmo81azy/
```

i am trying to select a range of weeks, like i should be able to select a 2 week or 3 weeks in a dates displayed, the calendar does show dates to cover up weeks

how can i fix it, i tried lot but i am missing something

JS Code

```
$(function () {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }
    var $weekPicker = $('.week-picker');

    function updateWeekStartEnd() {
        var date = $weekPicker.datepicker('getDate') || new Date();
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
    }

    updateWeekStartEnd();

    function updateDateText(inst) {
        var dateFormat = inst != 'start' &&  inst.settings.dateFormat ? inst.settings.dateFormat : $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
        
        console.log( dateFormat)
        $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings));
        $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));
    }

    //updateDateText('start');

    $weekPicker.datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            updateWeekStartEnd();
            updateDateText(inst);
            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate) cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    selectCurrentWeek();

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mousemove', function () {
        $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover');
    });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    });

});

<div class="week-picker"></div>
<br />
<br />
<label>Week :</label> <span id="startDate"></span> - <span id="endDate"></span>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is `$weekPicker` defined? What errors do you get or what specifically is not working? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/63mwc2tb/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  var startDate;
  var endDate;
  var $wp = $('.week-picker');
  var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy";

  function getWeekStartEnd(start, end) {
    if (start == undefined) {
      start = new Date();
    }
    if (end == undefined) {
      end = new Date(start);
    }
    start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay());
    end.setDate(end.getDate() - end.getDay() + 6);
    $("#start").val($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, start));
    $("#end").val($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, end));
    startDate = start;
    endDate = end;
  }

  function selectWeek() {
    $wp.find(".selected a").addClass('ui-state-active');
  }

  getWeekStartEnd();

  $wp.datepicker({
    dateFormat: dateFormat,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
      var dayClass = "";
      if (d >= startDate && d <= endDate) {
        dayClass += "ui-datepicker-current-day selected";
      }
      return [true, dayClass];
    },
    onSelect: function(dt, inst) {
      if ($(this).data("selected")) {
        endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, dt);
        $(this).data("selected", false);
        getWeekStartEnd(startDate, endDate);
      } else {
        startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, dt);
        $(this).data("selected", true);
        getWeekStartEnd(startDate);
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        selectWeek();
      }, 1);
    }
  }).data("selected", false);

  selectWeek();

  $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tr", $wp).on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $("a", this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
    },
    mouseout: function() {
      $("a", this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    }
  });
});
```

This uses a data attribute as a flag to see when the user has clicked the first time versus the second time. The rest is largely your same code with minor change.

Comment: Thanks, but i think that does not solve the issue i am having which is multiple week selection, do you mind to update your code with multiple week selection for the displayed month as that month shows full weeks if those weeks start and end with the next week or not. @Twisty

Comment: @will so you want to exclude days that are part of another month?

Comment: no, it will be part of the selected week, so if its ending or starting with previous week or next month week, it should be selected, and will it work with mouse selection

Comment: why the highlight is not showing on  week start, it was showing before, what change was made and i appreciate if you help to fix this code to handle multiple weeks . Thanks

Comment: @will, do you mean multiple individual weeks, like week 2 and week 4 or do you mean all weeks between, Week 2 through week 4?

Comment: both ways, should be able to select individual weeks and combined weeks